# 24-group rotation problem

Tags: combinatorics, rotations

I have 4 clans (A-D), each consisting 6 groups (1-6). Each group is supposed to play every game with a group from a different clan. There are a total of 8 games (15 min each). Each group has 12 blocks of 15 mins (i.e. 8 of games and 4 for rest).

IS there a logical way i can rotate them such that the above is met? The blocks for break time should ideally be consecutive, and each group should play with different groups from different clans.

Thank You!